# Inconsistent shapes in numpy arrays after slicing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-slicing

Following minimal example reproduces my problem:

```
import numpy as np
import random as rnd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


res = 10
nbnd = 3
E = np.empty([res, res, nbnd], dtype=float)


for kx in range(res):
    for ky in range(res):
        for n in range(nbnd):
            E[kx][ky][n] = rnd.random() + nbnd
            
print(E)
print(E.shape)


data = E[:][:][0]
print(data.shape)
plt.imshow(data, cmap='viridis', interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

For `data` I would expect shape `(10,10)`, but shape `(10,3)` is given. I do not see the forest for the trees... what's my problem here? TY!

Comment: (Just elaborating on @hpaulj) Because `E[1][2][3]` is the same as `E[1, 2, 3]`, it is a common mistake to believe that the latter is just a shorthand for the former.   But numpy is actually doing a lot of work behind the scenes to make the two equivalent.  In this case, where the indices aren't simple integers, the results are different.

Comment: `E[:,:,0]` will get `(10, 10)`